# How to find a one dimensional sufficient statistic.

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

Please could you help check my approach to finding a one dimensional sufficient statistic.

Here is the problem.

$X_1,...,X_n$ is a random sample with each $X_i$ having the pdf $f(x;\theta)=2\theta^2x^{-3} $ and $0<\theta\leq x<\infty$

**Approach**

$L(\theta;x)= \prod_{i=1}^n 2\theta^2x^{-3}_i $

$L(\theta;x)= 2^n \theta^{2n}x^{-3n}_i $

$L(\theta;x)= [2^n] [\theta^{2n}][x^{-3n}_i] $

So by factorisation theorem, $x^{-3n}_i$ is a sufficient statistic.

Is this right?

Comment: A friendly advice: [title is NOT the first sentence of your question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/356647). In particular, see the last bullet: the question post should be comprehensible without the title, even though one should make good use of the title to provide extra info.

Comment: No. $\prod x_i^{-3}=(\prod x_i)^{-3}$.

Comment: $\prod x_i^{-3}$ is not the same as $x^{-3n}$?

Comment: @MathsBarry Your sufficient statistic is $\prod_{i=1}^n x_i^{-3}=x_1^{-3}\ldots x_n^{-3}$; the $x_i$'s are not constant as you seem to think.